Source reference for QMA-completeness of the following pairwise product of Pauli matrices
The following pairwise Pauli matrices are sufficient to capture the power of QMA complexity class.
$\{I,\ I\otimes X,\ I\otimes Z,\ X\otimes I,\ Z\otimes I,\ X\otimes X,\ X\otimes Z,\ Z\otimes X, \ Z\otimes Z  \}$
as mentioned in equation 10 of [Biamonte and Love 2008].
The above paper refers to another paper by Dave Bacon:

The QMA-completeness of this subset of Hamiltonians was found independently by D. Bacon; preprint, (2007).

Query: I am unable to recover the above reference from the internet (D. Bacon's google scholar page).
I would like to see the proof of the QMA-completeness. Kindly let me know if someone has seen the proof or related resource for it.

Since the reference doesn't provide any details, I'm guessing it was a work in progress document that was shared with the authors. Maybe after their result came out, it wasn't pursued.

I think they only mention their completeness regarding generating generic time evolution for adiabatic (indeed not necessarily adiabatic) quantum computation. I would imagine this is simply related to their universality as a gate set. Namely just Z, X and ZZ are necessary. With Z and X you can generate arbitrary single qubit rotations and thus rotate ZZ into amy other two qubit rotation. Then you have any two-qubit rotation and thus a universal gate follows from there. I'm not sure if you need more than this for universality (at least in terms of dynamics, I'm not sure about ground states).
